# Not smooth animation of text resizing with TweenMax

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm trying to animate scale changing of MovieClip with textField child via TweenMax. It works but animation of textField isn't smooth. I can see text's resizing step by step.

```
        addChild(movieClip);
        var textField:TextField = new TextField();
        textField.x = 20;
        textField.y = 20;
        textField.width = 250;
        textField.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

        var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Tahoma");
        textFormat.size = 15;
        textFormat.bold = true;
        textField.setTextFormat(textFormat);

        movieClip.addChild(textField);
        TweenMax.to(movieClip, 2, {scaleX:2, scaleY:2});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
textField.embedFonts = true;
```

And actually embed the font in your swf.
When this option is not set, Flash uses the system font, so it can only display the text using the existing sizes which are integers, therefore the text will "jump" from size to size.

Comment: additionally, you want to make the text field anti-alias for animation. You can set it like so: `textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;`